# Keeping emails synchronized between Firebase auth and database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, serverless-framework

I am using Firebase Web for a SaaS solution. My purpose is to have access to users' email at any time, either for sending notifications or triggering alerts from the backend.

For security reasons, Firebase auth does not allow to list users' email or to fetch emails based on user IDs. As a consequence, I keep a copy of the email into a specific collection in the Firebase database when a user account is created. The copy is made by a Cloud function that is triggered on user creation (following guidelines: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions).

Thanks to the copy available in the Firebase database, I can access users' email. However, my issue is when a user changes his email.

Firebase auth provides the [updateEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address) function that returns a promise. I use this last to update the email in Firebase auth. Then, when the promise resolves I update the user email in the Firebase database. However, this has a major drawback: all the logic is performed on the client side and since both operations are not performed in a transaction if the client refreshes or closes his browser (or assume it crashes), then it is possible that Firebase auth is updated but not the Firebase database, thus leading to an inconsistent state.

I looked at the documentation, expecting the possibility to trigger a Cloud function when user auth information is updated. Unfortunately, I cannot find such a feature.

Another solution I thought about is to update the database from the Web client. Then, this last triggers a Cloud function that updates Firebase auth with the [admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#updateUser). This last solution works but bypasses the check performed by *updateEmail* that ensures the new email is not used by another account. Also, the [account hijacking protection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#updateEmail) performed by *updateEmail* is evicted, which is really bad from a security point of view.

Any idea to solve this problem properly is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

1. When calling updateEmail, update the email in your database first before calling updateEmail. THowever, if an error occurs, you need to catch it and undo that change in your db.
2. When a user wants to updateEmail, send their id token and new email to your server or firebase function http endpoint. There you verify the ID token with the admin SDK, then use the client SDK `require('firebase')`, using the uid from the ID token, `admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)`, then using client SDK, `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken)`. You can then call `user.updateEmail(newEmail)` on the backend and save the email.
3. Always save the uid only and just use Admin SDK `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` to look up the user and get their email. This guarantees you get the user's latest email as you will not be able to catch the email revocation if the user chooses to do so.
4. No need to save anything. Use the CLI SDK to download all your users and their emails. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport
   This is also better as you will always be able to get the latest email per user even if they revoke the email change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Suggestion 1) suffers from the same problems as what I have explained. For instance, the browser crashes after the email update in the database but before calling `updateEmail`.

Regarding 2), your suggestion is interesting but as you mention later it will not be able to manage the email revocation a user can perform.